# Is there a way to execute powershell commands remotely on a domain user from the DC?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Let's say for example, I have a domain controller and a client that is joined to the domain.
If I wanted to remotely lock out the client I would supposedly run

```bsh
Invoke-Command -ComputerName [workstation name] -ScriptBlock {rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation}
```

However this does not work. I'm assuming this is because the Invoke-Command cmdlet runs the code in the scriptblock but returns anything back to the local terminal. What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the code or powershell script run locally on the remote computer.

My question is first of all if this is the correct approach and second why the command I'm running does not work.

Comment: Lockout the client from the domain is a different thing than locking the remote host. Whether you have a DOmain controller involved or not. You can do what @Suman Chhetri is saying, there is no need to. Your command will only work if PowerShell Remoting has enabled on your machine and any remote target you plan to hit. You must also be in the local admin group of the remote target to do this. You can enable PSRemotiong using GPO for domain-joined machines, but for Workgroup machines, you have to do that manually. There's built-in help and samples on how to set up PS Remoting,  Web/Youtube

Comment: @postanote What my intention is, is to lock the remote host. Sorry for not being clear!
I'm trying to run any possible commands from a domain admin so I don't think permissions etc should be an issue. Various different commands seem to run perfectly it's just that apparently the command to lock out a remote host doesn't work.
I read somewhere else on a forum that supposedly _"Windows does not allow any process to manipulate an interactive user session."_ however if I run a remote command to **log off** a remote host, it works perfectly.

Comment: You cannot PowerShell commands in the context of a logged-on user. PowerShell always runs in the user context that started it. That is a Windows Security boundary that PowerShell respect. You can send a scheduled task to the target to run immediately or within a few seconds, set to run whether the user is logged on or not or use PSExec and other 3rdP tools can be used for that, but you have pass the interactive user parameters. See the PSExec help or [this](https://adamtheautomator.com/psexec-ultimate-guide)

Answer (score 0):

Download PsExec from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec and run following command.
`& "C:\PSTools\PsExec.exe" -s -i \\COMPNAME rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation`

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this exact command but psexec errors out and returns this:

`rundll32.exe exited on [remotehostname] with error code 0`

Comment: Is "Windows Remote Shell" enabled on the destination machines? Please enable it if not done already.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/555966

Comment: WinRM is enabled and configured on the server/DC however running Winrs on the client/remote host returns an access denied, which the link you provided does not cover.

Comment: Ok, so it is permission problem. Please try with a login ID which has needed permissions.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment when using PSExec... So, stuff like this ---

```
PsExec.exe \\ -d -u \Administrator -i cmd.exe /c "C:\windows\system32\rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation"
```

Or using PowerShell with quer.exe ...

(it's a tool in every modern Windows version)
[quser | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/quser)

...in a PowerShell remoting script, like described here:

> [How To Log Off Windows Users Remotely With PowerShell](https://blog.ipswitch.com/how-to-log-off-windows-users-remotely-with-powershell)

Again the work is being done by quser.exe, not PowerShell specifically. PowerShell is just being used to run quser.exe remotely. You could do the same, by copying PSExec to the remote host and do a similar operation.